# Delete relationship with UITableViewRowAnimationFade

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Say, I have an entity "Parent" which can have multiple "Child".  During deletion, I do this:

```
[self.parent removeChildObject:self.childToRemove];
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

With only that, the scene does not change and the row is not removed.  So what I did is I retrieve again all "Child" under that "Parent" and call

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

While it did it correctly, however, the deletion seems instantaneous.  The row just disappear in a blink of an eye.  I want it to animate with row fading.

I read that only the entity which was fetched using NSFetchedResultsController calls this delegate method "didChangeObject" where I put my row animation fade.  However, for retrieving the "Child", I didn't fetched it using the controller, but I fetched it from

```
[self.parent children];
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code should do it.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSArray * rowIndexPathArray = @[childObjectIndexPath];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowIndexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Where exactly should i placed the removechildobject and manageobjectcontext.save. Cause when i tried to put just the deleterowatindexpath just after save, i got an exception, and before save also got error

Comment: You need to save the objects outside the context in an NSMutableArray or an NSArray.  Remove the object from the array, update the table from that array, update the context separately.

Comment: The objects are already saved in NSArray as I am displaying them.  I tried putting your code before my removeChildObject method but my application hangs at endUpdates.  I hope you can clearly give the sequence given my previous code.